# When do the brachos mein shalosh exempt other brachos acharonos?

Tags: halacha, blessing, birkat-meeyn-shalosh

After eating the 5 grains or the 7 species or wine one recites a variant of the Mein Shalosh as the after blessing. On everything else one recites boreh nefashot.

Say you just ate an apple and a grape, what should you do?
What about if you had a grape with water?

Is there ever a case where reciting one of the mein shalosh variants exempts the person from reciting another bracha acharonah (such as borei nefashot)?

Comment: I would think some necessary followup questions would be whether the grape is more or less than a kezayis. The idea that it's a whole grape might mean that even if less than a kezayis, it gets a me'in shalosh but I dont know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [סימן נא - כללים בברכה אחרונה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0050_L2) :

> **סעיף י"ב**:
>   אָכַל פֵּרוֹת שֶׁבְּרָכָה אַחֲרוֹנָה שֶׁלָּהֶם בְּרָכָה מֵעֵין שָׁלֹשׁ, וְגַם פֵּרוֹת הָעֵץ שֶׁבְּרָכָה אַחֲרוֹנָה שֶׁלָּהֶן הוּא בּוֹרֵא נְפָשׁוֹת, מְבָרֵךְ בְּרָכָה מֵעֵין שָׁלֹשׁ. וְכֵיוָן שֶׁהוּא מַזְכִּיר בָּהֶם פְּרִי עֵץ, נִפְטָרִים בָּזֶה כָּל פְּרִי עֵץ שֶׁאָכַל. אֲבָל אִם נִתְחַיֵּב בִּרְכַּת בּוֹרֵא נְפָשׁוֹת עַל מִין אַחֵר, אֵינוֹ נִפְטָר בִּבְרָכָה מֵעֵין שָׁלֹשׁ, וִיבָרֵךְ תְּחִלָה בִּרְכַּת מֵעֵין שָׁלֹשׁ וְאַחַר כָּךְ בּוֹרֵא נְפָשׁוֹת. ‏

If you eat fruit that require a מֵעֵין שָׁלֹשׁ like grapes, figs, dates, olives and pomegranates and you also eat other fruit - like apples and oranges - then your מֵעֵין שָׁלֹשׁ will exempt you from making a בּוֹרֵא נְפָשׁוֹת.

However, if you require a בּוֹרֵא נְפָשׁוֹת for other food (besides for fruit - E.g. water, vegetables or meat) then you have to make a מֵעֵין שָׁלֹשׁ on the fruit and a בּוֹרֵא נְפָשׁוֹת on the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Another example would be an al hagafen (e.g. on wine) also exempts the borei nefashos on other drinks a person may have also drank (e.g. orange juice).

Answer (score 0):

Another example would be [rice](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65184/1516).(@Loewian, you really are the expert on this bracha!) Although the rice situation might be more complicated because of rice's uncertain status; I don't know.