# If you say mezonot on rice AND one of the five grains do you make two after blessings?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, mezonot-beracha, birkat-meeyn-shalosh

Mezonot is said on rice and a product of the five grains. However rice gets boreh nefashot as the after blessing while five grain products get al hamichya.

If you said one mezonot to cover both rice and 5 grain products, do you say a single al hamichya or do you add a boreh nefashot for the rice?

Lets assume you ate more than a kezayis of each and that the products or cooked or prepared in a way that would require you to make a mezonot on both.

Comment: Why might you think not to say both?

Comment: "that would require you to make a mezonot on both". I don't understand why you would have to make the same bracha twice.

Comment: @DanF He's not saying that you would make the beracha twice. He's specifying that the correct _beracha_ for both is _mezonot_ (i.e. we're not talking about raw wheat).

Comment: @DanF, One mezonot on both.

Comment: @AniYodea, that's a confusing way of saying that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Rabbi Ro'i Ganon](http://www.rabenu.co.il/he/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA/item/1186-%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%96), you only make an "*al hamichya*" (assuming rice is/has the same status as *orez*^):

> אם  אכל מאכל שברכת הראשונה "בורא מיני מזונות" וברכתו האחרונה היא "על המחיה", כגון: בורקס או ספגטי ( היינו תבשיל של מיני דגן או מאפה) ואכל מהם שיעור של כזית (היינו 27 גרם) ואכל גם אורז שיעור כזית, אף על פי שהיה צריך לכאורה לברך ברכת "על המחיה" על התבשיל ממיני דגן (או ממיני מאפה)  ועל האורז ברכת "בורא נפשות", מכל מקום לא יברך גם ברכת "על המחיה" וגם ברכת "בורא נפשות" אלא יברך "על המחיה" ובכך פוטר בברכתו את האורז.

The same ruling is also cited [here](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_15.html) from the *Yalkut Yosef* vol. 3 p. 485:

> האוכל אורז כשיעור, וגם עוגה כשיעור, יברך על המחיה, ויכוין לפטור את האורז. [ולא יברך נפשות על האורז]. [ילקוט יוסף, ח''ג דיני ברהמ''ז וברכות עמוד תפה]

We find a similar rule regarding one who has eaten both fruit that merit the blessing "*borei nefashoth*" (e.g. apples) and those that merit an "*al hapeiroth*" (e.g. grapes or figs); or one who drank both wine ("*al hagefen*") and other drinks ("*borei nefashoth*"). In all these cases, the "borei nefashoth" is omitted and only the *birkath me'ein shalosh* is recited.

^See e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CDMQFjADahUKEwjMxontlPzIAhULHD4KHS9dBus&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.etzion.org.il%2Fen%2Fdownload%2Ffile%2Ffid%2F3963&usg=AFQjCNEk5bapCJQp8t-QFCy0BegPjdyHXA&sig2=_INXSVmvj0JVo5ssgo7ySA&bvm=bv.106923889,d.cWw&cad=rja).

Comment: I think the difficulty is in that rice does not necessarily have the status of orez?

Comment: @SAH safeq brakhoth lehaqel

Comment: Fair enough. But in that case why do many say a Borei Nefashos (rather than no blessing) after rice alone?